# Does migrate.exe automatically downgrade the database schema if necessary?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

`Migrate.exe` is a command-line tool that comes with Entity Framework. 
When executing migrate.exe with the minimum amount of parameters, it is supposed to update the database schema with the latest migration:

```
Migrate.exe MyMvcApplication.dll
```

What happens if the latest migration included in my dll? Would migrate.exe downgrade the database automatically to the latest known migration from the dll or quit with an error? This does not seem to be included in the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I just tested the behavior and found that migrate.exe will not downgrade your database schema by default. In order to make it downgrade the database schema, the tool must be called like this:

```
 Migrate.exe MyMvcApplication.dll /targetmigration="MIGRATION_NAME" -Force
```